# Does this series converge? $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\sin^2\frac{1 }{\sqrt{k}}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

What should I do with such problems?

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\sin^2\frac{1  }{\sqrt{k}}$

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide an equivalent of $\sin^2{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}}$ ?

Comment: Try a limit comparison with $1/k^{3/2}$ and use the fact that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $k\to\infty$
$$\sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$$
(quotient $\to 1$) and
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\sin^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\approx\frac{1}{k^{3/2}},$$
So
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\sin^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$$
is converging because
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{3/2}}$$
is converging.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\sin x<x$ for $x>0$.

Hence,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt k}\sin^2\frac1{\sqrt k}\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-3/2}<\infty,
$$
since $\frac1{\sqrt k}>0$ for each $k\ge1$.